# Retrieve Current Mobile Foreground Application

Tags: android, ios, hybrid

I have been asked to implement an Hybrid Mobile application that is basically taking device's screenshots.

My issue is that I can't find a way to know which application is
currently running on foreground at the moment the screenshot is taken.

Example if the user is chatting on Facebook, I would like to be able to
register in my database that this screenshot has been taken when user
was chatting on Facebook.. Now user is using Twitter, then register that
this screenshot is coming from Twitter etc...

Is there a way to retrive this information? And off course it must work on Android and iOS

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I suppose it is impossible. At least on non-rooted devices.

Comment: I'd recommend you to research the on the following topic: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at it! Meanwhile..what is non-rooted devices in your words?